# What is the logic for making led high or low within given time?

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

To turn on the led the switch is to be pressed for 2 times,turn off the led the switch is to be pressed 3 times within 10 second?can any one explain the logic how to implement it?

I checked the status of a switch in delay function, but it's not working

```c
#include<reg51.h>


void delay_ms(unsigned int );


int count=0;
sbit sw=P2^0;
sbit led=P1^0;
main()
{

    while(1)
    {

    if(sw==0)
    {

     delay_ms(10000);   
    }
}


}
void delay_ms(unsigned int i)
{

    int j;
       for(i;i>0;i--)
         for(j=122;j>0;j--)
        {
                if(sw==0)
                {
                    while(sw==0);
                    count++;
                    if(count==2)
                         led=1;
                    if(count==3)
                         led=0;


                }

             }



}
```

expected result- switch pressed 2 times should turn on led and
                 switch pressed 3 times should turn off led (within 10 sec)

actual result- switch pressed 2 times should turn on led and
                 switch pressed 3 times should turn off led (but works without any time limit)

Comment: where did you put some kind of delay in the code?

Comment: In main function i checked the status of the switch, is the status is low(active low switch) then call the "delay_ms(10000)" function.

Comment: Let's go back to basics: What _exactly_ is the result you are getting and what results are you expecting? Does the `led` cycle, but just not with your 10 second limit? Some other results?

Comment: yes  daShier exactly, led will turn on for 2 presses and off for three presses but not in 10sec limit....

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? You never reset your `count` in `main()`

Comment: From a design and style perspective, a function called `delay_ms()` should in any case do nothing other than delay.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and more flexible solution (in an application where you might need to do other work concurrently), is to timestamp the switch events and compare the current event time with the previous timestamps.

Given a regular time source (assuming the standard `clock()` here but the logic is valid regardless) :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>  // for memset()
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isSwitchEvent()
{
    sbit sw = P2^0 ;
    bit current_sw = sw ;
    static bit previous_sw = sw ;

    // NOTE: Ignoring switch bounce issues - different question

    // Switch event when state *changed* to 1->0...    
    bool switch_event = (current_sw == 0 && previous_sw == 1) ;
    previous_sw = current_sw ;

    return switch_event ;
}

#define SWITCH_PERIOD CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 10
int main()
{
    sbit led = P1^0;

    // Initialise so that first switch event is guaranteed to be at
    // least then 10 seconds later than the initial timestamps.
    clock_t switch_timestamp[3] = {-SWITCH_PERIOD, 
                                   -SWITCH_PERIOD, 
                                   -SWITCH_PERIOD } ;
    unsigned i = 0 ;
    bit led_state = 0 ;
    bool change = false ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // On switch event...
        if( isSwitchEvent() )
        {
            // Timestamp event
            switch_timestamp[i] = clock() ;

            // If LED off, and previous event was less 
            // than 10 seconds ago...
            if( led_state = 0 && 
                switch_timestamp[i] - switch_timestamp[(i+2)%3] < SWITCH_PERIOD )
            {
                // LED on
                led_state = 1 ;
                change = true ;
            }
            // else if LED on, and previous two events were less 
            // than 10 seconds ago...
            else if( led_state = 1 && 
                     switch_timestamp[i] - switch_timestamp[(i+1)%3] < SWITCH_PERIOD )
            {
                // LED off
                led_state = 0 ;
                change = true ;
            }

            // If LED state change...
            if( change )
            {
                // Set output to the prevailing LED state 
                led = led_state ;

                // Make timestamps older that SWITCH_PERIOD so 
                // previous events are not to be counted
                // for next LED state change.
                switch_timestamp[0] = clock() - SWITCH_PERIOD ;
                switch_timestamp[1] = switch_timestamp[0] ;
                switch_timestamp[2] = switch_timestamp[0] ;

                // Next timestamp
                i++ ;
                i %= 3 ;
            }
        }

        // You can do other work here (so long as 
        // it does not take so long as to miss a 
        // switch event).
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not providing any debounce for your switch. Also where is `count` being initialized? I don't see it.

You need to have a delay when you detect the switch closed because it will "bounce" open and closed many times in the first few milliseconds. I would delay for at least 10mS before checking to see if the switch has been opened and then you can change your `count`.

**UPDATE BASED ON OP COMMENTS:**

Well again, this would *only* work in simulation. Switches are not that good. But I do see your issue: You don't reset `count` in your `main()`. Try:

```c
    main()
        {
        while(1)
           {
           count = 0;
           if(sw==0)
               {
               delay_ms(10000);   
               }
           } 
        }
```

Comment: since i am checking in the Proteus simulator i think debounce  is not an issue? and i have initialized the count also.

Comment: `count` will only be `==2` for an instant, then `==3` for another instant, then it will increment well past anything you care about.

Comment: that's why i have included "while(sw==0)"  in the delay function

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer because it appears you are saying your simulation works, just doesn't have the 10 second limit. That's due to not resetting `count` in `main()`. However, you still have the switch debounce issue if you intend to move it to "real" hardware. Your loop where you increment `count` doesn't allow for debounce.

Comment: well daShier i agree with you about debounce issue in "real hardware", but my issue is if we press the switch, then it is in delay function for 10 sec and it will count how many time switch is pressed after 10 sec it should not work. but its working